# Can't Get Count of More than one table fields Through Linq Query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

My Aggregate Query

```cs
var attendanceAggregate = (from ed in _context.EmployeeDetail 
    join uf in _context.userInfo on ed.employeeCode equals uf.SSN
    join ct in _context.EmployeeContract on ed.employeeCode equals ct.EmployeeCode
    join chio in _context.checkinout on uf.USERID equals chio.USERID
    join vlr in _context.LeaveRequest.Where(v => v.VerifiedByHR != null)
                                    .Where(s => s.RequestDate >= FromDate && s.RequestDate <= ToDate) 
                on ct.ContractID equals vlr.ContractID into vlri
    from vlr in vlri.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join tlr in _context.LeaveRequest.Where(v => v.ApprovedBy != null && v.RequestedBy != null && v.RejectedBy == null)
                                    .Where(s => s.RequestDate >= FromDate && s.RequestDate <= ToDate) 
                on ct.ContractID equals tlr.ContractID into tlri 
    from tlr in tlri.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where uf.USERID == chio.USERID && chio.CHECKTIME != null 
          && chio.CHECKTIME >= FromDate && chio.CHECKTIME <= ToDate
    group new { ed, chio, ct, vlr, tlr } by new
    {
        ed.employeeCode,
        ed.name,
        ed.surName,
        ed.nameDari,
        ed.surNameDari
     } into g
     select new
     {
        g.Key.name,
        //fullName = _culture.GetLanguageId() == 1 ? g.Key.name + ' ' + g.Key.surName : g.Key.nameDari + ' ' + 
        g.Key.surNameDari,
        code = g.Key.employeeCode,
        TotalPendingRequest=g.Count(s=> s.tlr.LeaveRequestID != null)
    }).ToList();
```

and error that occured to me

> '.Count(s => (Nullable)s.tlr.LeaveRequestID != null)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Comment: The error is clear. You wouldn't put a `WHERE` inside a `COUNT` in SQL either. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL and this huge query is a clear example of a case where you *shouldn't* use LINQ. It would make sense to use LINQ up to a point if there were proper relations between the entities, so you wouldn't have to write any of those `join`s

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Was this query generated dynamically? Is that why there are multiple `Where()` calls in some joins? This query could be simplified a lot with the proper relations. There would be no need for any of the `join`s. Filtering for all entities can be performed in a single `where` clause at the end. On the other hand, a SQL View with some LEFT JOINs a Where and a Group By would probably be clearer anyway

Comment: Iam using ef 4 i generate the query first in sql than after that i write the query in linq the query that i generated in linq is working correct with same joins and sam where clause. but in linq is not working

Comment: If you use JOIN in EF/LINQ, you have a bug. It's EF's job to generate the JOINs from the entity relations. EF doesn't have tables, a DbContext isn't a database model. LINQ is meant to simplify querying. The query you posted here is *very* hard to read

Comment: So i have to use store procedure instead of linq here ??

Comment: the main problem is that in  this query when i get max record it works but when i try to count any field than counting is not working

Comment: The main problem is that the query is unreadable and misuses LINQ.  You have to clean up this query. Either use proper relations so you can get rid of all those JOINs and nested Wheres, or use a stored procedure or function. Definitely remove `Count(s=> s.tlr.LeaveRequestID != null)`. That makes little sense in SQL. If you wanted to count non-null rows, why not use that condition in `Where` ?

Comment: that where condition is that iam taking exact record of leave that matches it's date with attendance records the system structure is like that leave request does not have any relation with attendance check in and out table but through left join iam trying to get matched record by it's date time

Answer (score 0):

This question needs details about EF Core version. EF Core 5 can translate this query but not earlier versions. But there is workaround using `Sum`

```cs
...
    select new
    {
        g.Key.name,
        g.Key.surNameDari,
        code = g.Key.employeeCode,
        TotalPendingRequest = g.Sum(s => s.tlr.LeaveRequestID != null ? 1 : 0)
    }
```

Comment: Sum is working but i want count the total record of leave request

Comment: This is not described in your question. Any SQL analogue of `count the total record of leave request`?

Comment: tnx for Your Help My Problem is Solved With Sql Procedure